# Gravity form working

Tags: wordpress, performance, forms, gravity

i'm using gravity form developer license and 1.7.9 version

Grvity form working slow. it takes some time for processing.

i'm working on calculation product field, so when check box get click it should update the

calculations. but somehow the entire form working slow. please provide me any solution

Answer (score 0):

why not use [this one](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-plugin/) or [this one](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/).

I mostly use the last one, works perfect and you can make a lot of different contact forms with little effort.